# How to change the shape of a smart object in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I downloaded a photoshop mockup file which contains "floating screens" (see below).
[image]

In photoshop, these screens are created with smart objects.

[image]

So, when I double click on the smart object mask-layer, photoshop opens up that layer in a second window and shows me a plain flat non-distorted shape. I can then nicely paste my image, save that second window and close it again. What I didn't figure out so far, is, how do I change the size of these shapes? Because as soon as I want to make them smaller, they get all distorted, the edge radius doesn't look nice anymore, etc:

[image]

So, to summarize my question: How do I resize (or crop?) a smart object shape, so when I double click on it and it opens in a new window, the flat/non-distorted shape is also resized? Is there maybe a way to make these floating screens flat again (standard rectangular shape), resize them and then distort them again into the final perspective view?

I hope I explained that well.

Comment: Though this *is* on topic here, I feel you may do better posting it on https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: The method is to select the smart object layer in the Layers panel, go to *Edit > Transform > Scale* or use Ctrl+T and resize it using the bounding box. You should be careful not to distort the aspect ratio. If it contains an image that is non-vector, it may not scale nicely. If this doesn't work for you, please post online a small example.

Comment: @harrymc I tried the standard CTRL+T, but as you mentioned, that only works when keeping the aspect ratio. Any idea on how to change the aspect ratio without making a mess?

Comment: I always avoid changing the aspect ratio of images except by a little bit because the result is distorted. A pixel image can get all jagged and weird, but less so if it's high resolution. A vector-based image will scale better and distort less, although it's more suited to geometric figures.

Comment: @harrymc got it - is there any way to show the transformation angles that have been used on a shape? When I used CTRL+T, change an angle and accept the changes, I don't see the original tilting angles anymore. If I could find out the tilting angles in all axes, I could simply create a custom sizes shape and then tilt it myself.